# apps(tasks) restarting even after killing them

Tags: task-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do I really need to install a task manager?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-i-really-need-to-install-a-task-manager)
>   [apps automatically starting?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/apps-automatically-starting)
>   [How can I stop applications and services from running?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/1465)

I have some apps running in background using cpu all the time and draining my batery. I want to stop them.

I have a latest `task manager` to kill the background tasks but BUT some of the tasks(apps) are restarting even after killing them, WHY ?

Is there any way to permanently kill a particular task ?

Comment: [Disable autostart on boot and restrict background execution](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these tasks are services. 
And I think the developer starts the service `START_STICKY` which means, the service get every time restored if killed (normaly not through a taskmanager, only on low memory). 
I would suggest you, to remove the task manager. Android is not designed, that the tasks get killed. 
 If Android need memory, the system frees the ram on it own.

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to stop START_STICKY services ?

Comment: No,  sorry. It has a sense that the services are sticky.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Leandros' answer, if you want to prevent these services from running the only real option is to uninstall the app that owns them.  For system apps you'll need root, and to be careful not to remove something that's needed by the system.

[Autostarts](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts) can edit which apps receive which events — some apps start based on your network connectivity and so on — but services designed to run constantly can't be changed this way.

Comment: I don't want to remove apps.i want to stop them runnening in background. Is there any terminal command to do this?

Comment: @sam From above: "if you want to prevent these services from running the only real option is to uninstall the app that owns them".

Comment: BTW, Autostarts is free software (= open-source), also [available from f-droid.org](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=autostart&fdid=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts), which is important to know for those who don't want to install non-free software (non-community-reviewed, possibly malicious code).

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev Please stop spamming that comment.

Comment: @MatthewRead I wanted to write down helpful information; it would help me when I was in search of such an app. Of course, unfortunately, you'll get all those notifications for the new comments--I'm sorry for this! (But I couldn't do this improvement without disturbing you with the notifications at SE, unfortunately.)

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev I'm not worried about the notifications for myself, but it's a side note at best.  It's not appropriate to add this everywhere the app is mentioned regardless of context.