# How do I view and manage the list of Intents that launch what apps in my phone? How do I unregister these apps?

Tags: applications, alarm

During the day I notice that many of my installed apps run themselves automatically. For example, FB all of a sudden asks my GPS data or reads my contact list, without me launching the FB app.  FB does not have a persistent notification icon, so I do not expect it to be a background process.  Yet using Intents, apps do what it wants when it wants.

I want to be able to know -- then stop or control -- what apps launch by themselves in my device. I hope that's a fair thing to ask.

Comment: possible duplicate of [apps automatically starting?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2258/apps-automatically-starting)

Comment: @eldarerathis That question explains why apps launch by themselves. I want to know **what** these apps are, **which** intents they are hooked to and **how** to unregister them.  The answers to that question also observe that apps are "pretty well-behaved". The FB app I used as an example is, in my opinion, not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are rooted, install [Autorun Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun). Make sure you've [Busybox](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Busybox&c=apps) installed and use `Advanced Mode` of Autorun Manager. It displays all receivers of an app as well as intents to which receivers are registered. From there, you can disable a receiver of an app, too. But, you'd need [pro version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rs.autorun.pro) if you want to disable more than two receivers.

Answer (score 0):

The only real way to control these apps is to remove them. Android doesn't provide any fine-grained settings to control the odd behaviors of individual apps.