# Android 2.2 - How to see applications that run at start-up

Tags: applications, boot, auto-start

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I prevent applications from running on startup?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/158/how-can-i-prevent-applications-from-running-on-startup)

Hello!

Is it possible to see which applications are set to run at startup?
For example, the idiots at Yahoo made the Android Messenger so that it starts on Android Start-up, but provide no way of preventing this behaviour. They always do this kind of dirty tricks...

Anyway, is there sort of an `msconfig` as in Windows?

Thank you.

Comment: If you logout from Yahoo Messenger, it will not automatically login when you reboot your phone.

Comment: I know, I killed the process, but I want to see which apps start after rebooting and change that if needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know of a free solution, though there may be one.

I do know of [Autostarts](http://www.appbrain.com/app/autostarts/com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts), currently just under 1 USD, a pretty good price in my opinion. It gives you a list of applications that have attached themselves to different events in the Android OS (I'm not an Android programmer, my wording is likely wrong there). You can then choose to disable that association without actually removing or disabling the application. For your Yahoo startup example -- With Autostarts you can prevent it from launching on startup, but it will still be accessible for you to launch at your leisure later on.

Forgot to mention - this does require root. A bit of searching seems to confirm that there is no way to disable startup apps without root - your only option in that case would be uninstalling them.

I also stumbled on a manual process that I've never personally tried -- You can do what Autostarts does by issuing some shell commands (ADB or Terminal Emulator app).

```
su pm disable <package name>/<package name>.<activity name>
```

I believe that would translate to something like:

```
su pm disable com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.im/com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.im.android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

But I've never tried this myself.

Comment: Thank you, Saiboogu. Excellent answe, I pressed `set as accepted` 9 times! Hope that counts for something. :)

Comment: The info in the answer (talking about price) is not complete: Autostarts is free software (= open-source), also [available from f-droid.org](http://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdfilter=autostart&fdid=com.elsdoerfer.android.autostarts), which is important to know for those who don't want to install non-free software (non-community-reviewed, possibly malicious code).

Answer (score 3):

There is an application called Startup Cleaner (Free). Startup Cleaner does not require root, however just like Saiboogu said, you cannot actually prevent application from starting up without rooting. Startup Cleaner register itself at boot time, and then kills applications that you want to prevent from starting up at boot time; and after some time it kills itself.

Comment: Thank you Lie, I'll see about Startup Cleaner as well. Thanks.

Comment: I've used similar apps, unfortunately they often cause problems and most apps just start up again later.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided not to go down that road. I generally dislike "cleaner" apps etc from my Windows OS experience.

Comment: which is precisely why I uninstalled that apps as well; though it might be a viable alternative if you don't want to root.