# Bypassing a software that loads on startup

Tags: applications, auto-start, motorola-droid-xyboard

I recently acquired a Motorola Droid XYBoard loaded with GoPago. This software starts up immediately and I was wondering if there is a way to either bypass it or access the operating system around it.

Comment: Please see [How can I prevent applications from running on startup?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/158/16575)

Comment: The thing is, as far as I can tell the only thing you can do with this device (out of the box) is use it with the software. This isn't that it starts immediately, this is that it seems only capable of running this software.

Comment: @Garan If your question isn't simply how to not run it, you should add more details to your question to explain precisely what you're trying to achieve.