# Clearing System Storage & Ram

Tags: storage, system

Is there any other way to clear System Storage and Ram on my phone? I have a Samsung Galaxy Pocket. I can clear some Ram thru Task Manager, and all apps (that will allow it) have been moved to the sd card. Any music, photos or videos are on my External SD Card.
I dont run and widgets either.
Please help!

Comment: RAM is main memory, do you mean internal storage?

Comment: @MatthewRead I guess the OP really means RAM – taking the context (task manager). Tried to cover it all with my answer nevertheless :)

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no need to "clear RAM" (see our [ram tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/ram/info) for details).

Second, task-killers are rather to be avoided for all but very specific cases: they are useful when an app goes bonkers, but their purpose is not to clear/clean anything. For this topic, please see:

- [Is it advisable to run a task killer app on Android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/519/16575)
- [Do task killers actually work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/18765/16575)

Third, "clear System Storage" is certainly not what you have in mind literally (`/system` storage is mounted read-only, and basically is where "the OS" resides). Clearing storage is a different thing when it comes to the parts writeable: cache, apps you've installed (including their data), files you've downloaded (eBooks, music, videos). Now ***that's*** something which can be pretty useful. There are several apps available for [Storage Analysis](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/file_storageanalysis), helping you to find the "big chunks" to delete selectively. And there are even more apps helping you with [System Cleanup](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systemcleaner) directly.

Not to forget what you could do even without those helpers: Walk the list of the apps you've installed (in *Settings › Apps*), and uninstall those you no longer need. What's not there cannot use up precious storage, and cannot waste resources like CPU, RAM, or network bandwidth.