# Android 2.1 - MyTouch Slide 3G - Tips to Fixing Slow Phone & Poor Battery Life

Tags: performance, battery-life, htc-mytouch-3g-slide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone)

What are the best applications or best practices for fixing slow operating phones and poor battery life on Android 2.2?

I use task killer but it doesn't seem to help that much. I wish there was an automatic task killer that would automatically prevent letting useless applications run in the background. I'm tired of doing a factory restore on my phone every month after it slows down to a screeching halt. Do you think it's worth upgrading to the G2 or does the G2 have the same problems?

Comment: You should not be using a task killer.

Comment: @AlEverett, What should I use?

Comment: Nothing. You don't need a task killer. See, for instance, this question: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-i-really-need-to-install-a-task-manager