# Find a list of all apps that launch at boot time

Tags: boot, auto-start

I am using Android 5.1.1 (EDIT: 6.0.1 now) in a Samsung J7.
I want to get a list of apps that launch at boot time<sup>1</sup>.

**What are the alternative clear ways of identifying such list? (preferably native from Android)**

I could not find anything native. I did find other options/posts, but I am not sure how certain were the posters about the methods, with contradicting info, so I explicitly ask:

1. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8710/81584) gives [Android Assistant](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.advancedprocessmanager) as an option.
   I installed it, and checked *Monitoring* -> *Startup Manager*
   It shows two tabs (*User*, *System*) with lists of apps<sup>2</sup>.
   The two lists total 41+83=124 apps.
   [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en), AlarmReceiver (I could not identify this app) and [Maps.Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps.pro) are in the first list, e.g.
   There is no mention to any permission.
   This *would* do the job.
2. [This answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/8713/81584) suggests checking the list of apps that have [RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission, among [the list of 138 permissions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).
   This would list apps that *are able to* launch at startup (although not necessarily doing so?).
   [Permission Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.carlocriniti.android.permission_explorer) shows 151 apps with this permission.
   [aSpotCat](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.aSpotCat) shows 68 apps with this permission.
   [App Permission Watcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.struse.apewatch) shows 48 apps that can “run at startup” without specifically quoting the name of the permission; for instance, this does not list Skype, which shows up in the other two. This might be checking User apps, but then 48<>41, and AirDroid or Maps.Me are not in here.
   [Permission Friendly Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.androidsoft.app.permission) also shows 48 apps that can run at startup<sup>3</sup>; it does not list Skype.

So at this point, I do not know which is a sure way, and what is each app checking...

---

<sup>1</sup> At this point, I do not mean to modify the startup list, but only check it.

<sup>2</sup> Moreover, there is a checkbox for each app to *Select ítems to kill on startup*.

<sup>3</sup> I did not check if these are all the same as App Permission Watcher.

Comment: You could use ADB to list the active receivers. That's not just the apps having the `BOOT_COMPLETED` permission granted, but those having established a listener to the event by the same name. Something along the lines of `adb shell "dumpsys package" | grep enabledComponents` (just an example, not a script that would exactly do the job you're after; that would need to be a bit more sophisticated :)

Answer (score 3):

On Android 7+, you can do:

```
~$ pm query-receivers --components -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Or:

```
~$ dumpsys package resolvers receiver | awk '/android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED/{p=1;next}/:/{p=0}p {print $2}'
```

Related: [Disable autostart on boot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209345/218526)

---

Self promoting my app [WhatsRunning](https://github.com/mirfatif/WhatsRunning). Please check [Auto-Starting Apps](https://mirfatif.github.io/WhatsRunning/help/en#auto-start-app-detail), [Alarms](https://mirfatif.github.io/WhatsRunning/help/en#alarm-detail) and [Scheduled Jobs](https://mirfatif.github.io/WhatsRunning/help/en#sched-job-detail).

Related: [Prevent Android apps from starting on device boot](https://mirfatif.github.io/IAnswers/prevent_android_apps_start_on_boot)

Answer (score 2):

Open memory in your settings then select App started on boot

[image: Settings]

Comment: There is no such option in my stock Android Marshmallow (Nexus 6). Please mention your device name and Android version.

Comment: OnePlus One.  Android N 7.1.1 Linage OS