# How to know apps which boots with system using commands in Android terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, auto-start

I need commands for Android 4-6. How to know via Android terminal and command which apps loading on the system's start?

While I tried 2nd command from [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217212/386406).

Comment: By "Android terminal" you mean `adb`? Because Android has no other terminal by default.

Comment: I mean I can use commands in Android.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find a list of all apps that launch at boot time](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217212/218526)

Comment: Thank you. I need time to check an information there.