# Samsung Galaxy S2 hangs/freezes sometime

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, samsung-galaxy-s-2, crashes, system-freeze

I am using Samsung Galaxy S2 for last 4 days. After two days of usage, I am experiencing phone hanging frequently. It just freezes while operating. The screen light won't go off and screen stays freezed. Only way out is press & hold power off button and restart S2.

I was using a launcher called, Go Launcher EX. Thinking this launcher is making the problem, I uninstalled everything related to this. But it didn't fix the problem.

I am running the following applications other than the defaul samsung installed ones.

1. Advanced task killer
2. Amazon Kindle
3. Angry birds
4. Dropbox
5. Facebook
6. Firefox
7. Gmail
8. Picture Dial
9. Springpad

I am not sure which application causes the problem. I am thinking of doing a factory reset. Before I do that, just wanted to see if someone else faced the problem.

If the crash/freeze happens next time, is there a place that I can look for diagnostic information? Like logs, dumps etc.

Edit

I got it freezing again. I was charging the phone and got a call. That froze the phone.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: How often do you use the task killer? Because you really shouldn't.

Comment: I use it whenever I see lot of applications are running. I heard, it is good to use that. Why do you think it should be run often?

Comment: No, you shouldn't use the task killer at all. See http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-i-really-need-to-install-a-task-manager

Answer (score 1):

If you suspect an app or service is causing the freeze, and if your phone is rooted, install [Bloat Freezer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bloatfreezer.free) and then freeze  background apps and services in groups to try and isolate the problem.
A good list of apps that can be safely frozen can be found [here](http://samsunggalaxysforums.com/archive/index.php/t-4811.html). Some of them are:

- All share
- Analog clock
- Android live wallpapers
- Ap Mobile
- Bookstore

There are over a hundred listed in the post I've referenced.