# Are there specific cases in which a task-killer or "fast reboot" program is helpful?

Tags: performance, ram, task-management

I know there have been previous questions regarding task killers, but I wanted to ask about two specific cases.

I've heard a debate raging here and on several forums about Android's way of managing apps and the use of task killers, (examples here[enter link description here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9/do-i-really-need-to-install-a-task-manager) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/do-task-killers-actually-work) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/do-task-killers-actually-work)), in which one side says that Android manages tasks just fine but the other side insists that their phone does indeed slow down and a task killer helps.

So my questions are these.

1) Could task killers or "[reboot apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot&hl=en)" conceivably help for a program that has high CPU usage and simply needs to be restarted?  I'm not necessarily talking about malicious apps, but reputable apps that tend toward higher CPU usage the longer they run?  I'm assuming that if an app always has high CPU usage a task killer will not help as it will likely restart, and should just probably be uninstalled altogether.

2)  In the case of a launcher that slows down over time, would a task killer or reboot app be helpful, simply in restarting it (similar to case 2, but I'm not sure lag in a specific app is directly correlated with its CPU usage).  I know that when I used third-party launchers, I had more lag issues as opposed to using the basic AOSP launcher (Android's own default launcher, often replaced by phone vendors own version).

Any other specific cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, I don't believe so. If you need to stop an app, you can always go to Settings > Applications > Manage Applications, click on the app and force stop. It does the same thing and the only time I find myself clicking on it, is when an app is acting up.

Comment: Good point. I keep forgetting about the native tools to do such things.