# Can I reinitialize specific core services?

Tags: wi-fi, 2.2-froyo, bluetooth, services

Sometimes my phone gets into a state where one of the core functions - audio, wifi, bluetooth - is in a somehow broken state. Example symptoms:

- wifi cannot see any available networks
- wifi attempts to connect but always fails
- other devices cannot connect to wifi tethering hotspot
- bluetooth cannot see any other devices
- bluetooth connection to headset is established, but no audio comes through
- it is impossible to turn bluetooth on (any attempt just processes for a while, and bluetooth remains off)
- audio doesn't play anything at all, not to an external device nor through internal speaker (and yes, the volume is set correctly)
- audio output is stuck at very low volume

Rebooting the phone *always* fixes the issues in these conditions. However, rebooting this thing takes a silly amount of time, especially if you count in the initialization phase where the phone is online, but so laggy you practically can't do anything.

**Is there a way to restart / reinitialize specific core services without rebooting? How?**

Note: I'm *not* talking about turning the features on/off from settings of from a widget. It does help in some cases, but not always.

The phone is [GT-S5570](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_GT-S5570) running Android 2.2.1. The phone is rooted, so solutions that require root are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this app or similar ones like this  -  [**Fast Reboot - Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot).

You could also try disabling some apps from auto starting via apps like these - [Startup Manager - Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=imoblife.startupmanager)

Another thing to do could be to install a custom ROM, which may have lesser bloatware but may come at expense of stability. In custom ROMs you may also have option to disable boot-animations, although the difference wouldn't be much.

Comment: Thanks! Though these are attempts at doing a faster reboot, which isn't exactly what I'm asking. They do address the underlying problem, though.

Comment: The description of Fast Reboot sounds really dubious. *"Simulates a reboot by closing/restarting all core and user processes and thus frees up memory. Your phone should be much snappier after using Fast Reboot."* While rebooting the core processes sounds like it might be applicable in my case, I'm not very happy using an app that is based on the [false](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9) [claim](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19202) of a performance boost because of memory management issues.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try hot booting?

> If your Android device starts acting funny, what do you do? That’s right, you reboot the device and everything goes back to normal. But, what if there was a faster way to solve your issues? Many times, the culprit of any and all failures is the shell itself. This can be easily terminated via any of the available task managers out there, but here is a better solution. XDA member appelflap has developed an app that will only reboot the Android shell. This has several advantages, like the fact that you will not have to go through menus and/or lists of apps to find the shell to stop it. Also, it is faster than performing a soft reset. And best of all, it is a one touch kill.

Source: http://www.xda-developers.com/windows-mobile/reboot-the-shell-only-with-hot-reboot-for-android/

Unfortunately I couldn't find the app the developer made. The linked application thread only contains the text "On Market now" with no name or anything to follow up.

So you might want to try searching on Play store for Hot reboot.

In my HTC Desire running ICS there is option to Hot reboot which boots my phone from boot animation. I'm not sure but I do feel its a tleast twice faster than normal reboot. There are some claim that hot reboot is twice faster as well. For eg: http://www.intomobile.com/2010/09/29/hot-reboot-android-video/

Answer (score -1):

The fact that you are rooted is great, because that means that you can isolate the problem by trying to switch to another ROM. If the problem disappears, then it was software related and it's then solved :)

I suggest you look at [Galaxy Mini Android Development](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1314) on xda-developers and find a ROM that you think looks nice. (I'm noting one of them now has the word "wifi fix" in it). Don't forget to install a custom kernel after the ROM if the instructions tell you to do so, you don't want to run a flashy new ROM with an old kernel.

The reason new ROM + kernel is something that's important to try is that these components regulate the functions you mentioned (wifi, bluetooth etc), so by replacing them completely we know if there might be a hardware malfunction or if there was some kind of software bug to begin with.

Comment: Yeah, switching to another ROM might be a good idea to solve the issues. Doesn't really answer the question about restart the core services, though.