# Are Memory Cleanup Apps for Android Good or Bad?

Tags: task-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do task killers actually work?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18765/do-task-killers-actually-work)

I was just going through this article on [Lifehacker](http://lifehacker.com/5650894/android-task-killers-explained-what-they-do-and-why-you-shouldnt-use-them).

Do these kind of apps really help in performance, or do they create more problems?

Comment: In short! Do not *even* contemplate that as Android is smart with memory management! Those task-killer subjects have been discussed countless of times, and do no justice either! IT would have been true for versions < Gingerbread, i.e. Froyo, Eclair. Gingerbread upwards are better at managing memory....

Comment: Thanks. My understanding about the article was correct then. I will be using the built-in task manager always.

Comment: There have been multiple questions here on this very topic. Look at some of the questions in the [tag:task-manager] tag.