# How can I verify that a widget updates only when it's visible?

Tags: app-widgets

I've installed a task manager widget that shows me the amount of free memory I currently have in the icon of the widget. When I look at it it updates every ~3 seconds, so it definitely drains some battery and consumes some memory when it's active and updating.

I want to make sure it doesn't update when the widget is invisible:

- When screen is turned off.
- When another app is running.
- When widget is placed on another (invisible) home screen tab.

How can I check whether the widget updates only when it's visible or even when it's invisible?

Comment: Closely related: [Do widgets run if not on current home screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36209/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't update only when it's visible. Because all widgets are drawn by the *host* (i.e. the home screen or lock screen), there's no way for the widget *provider* to tell whether the widget is visible or not.

It would be possible for the *service* that keeps changing the widget to find out when the screen is turned off. In recent Android versions, you could verify that using the **Battery** screen in **Settings**. Add the widget to your home screen, then (while the phone/tablet isn't plugged in) leave the screen turned off for some time. Turn it back on, and see if your task manager app is listed on the **Battery** screen.

Regardless of the result, your task manager app is probably doing more harm than good. Android isn't like Windows: it's designed to keep as much memory in use as it can, and only frees memory when it has to. See [Do I really need to install a task manager?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9/12442) for more info.