# Unwanted processes

Tags: battery, sony-xperia-sp

I bought a Sony Xperia SP phone 3 days ago.
Nice, fast, everything is seems to be all right, except for 2 things:

Last night, I killed all the tasks, set the stamina mode, and charged it to 100%. I went to sleep at 23:00, my alarm woke me up at 7:30 (GMT+1 where I am).

I checked my phone, and WTF? Battery is on 86%. No wifi, nfc, gps, bluetooth, anything was turned on, and as I mentioned, it was in stamina mode.

I checked the task list, and there were a lot of tasks, that I did not start, I don't touch my phone while I sleep (obviously).

I made a check again today. Killed all of the tasks except:

- Advanced
- Task Manager
- Lookout
- Clean Master
- Messenger / Facebook. (I do not know why I did not kill this,
  because I am using stamina mode, but never mind).

After I killed all of the tasks except those mentioned above, went to home screen, back to task manager, and guess what:

Now running

- YouTube
- Google Play Newsstand (hungarian lang)
- Google+
- Facebook
- Google Play services
- Chrome
- Google search
- FourSquare
- McAfee Security
- Intelligent Link
- HRS Hotels

etc...

Why is it happening? (Who the fffffff asked to start HRS Hotels for example?)
Ok, if Google search has reloaded itself, I say, ok, or some Google apps, but the others?

How can I stop these apps starting automatically?

The problem is, I check what uses the most of the battery power, and it says: Google Services 22%, Map, 19%.

I checked Google services and here are the list of packages (I tried to translate from Hungarian):

- Account manager
- Google Play framework
- Google Play services
- Network location
- Bookmark synch
- Google contact sync

Ok, I did enable these services, but this whole thing is strange for me.
Please help me to improve to use my battery for longer use.

Thx

Comment: Please check: [How can I stop applications and services from running?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/30332/16575) / [Do I really need to install a task manager?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/9/16575)

Comment: @lolka_bolka Believe me, I would love to have this control. This is one of the reasons why I rooted my device. Now I can control what is running and using internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android is not designed to let you control what is running and what not. A badly developed app can drain your power overnight.

In such a case a reboot can improve the situation for a while.

However if you encounter pre-installed apps running you never want to use you can disable them under Settings -> Apps.

Afterwards they can not be started anymore, neither manually by the user nor automatically.

Comment: Ok, i realized, all the google synch was enabled, i turned off a lot of them. And download a good app manager (yes, i could uninstall them by manually through settings), and removed unwanted applications. I will check tomorrow morning, what is the difference.  What i realized, google stops starting a lot of services, but facebook and messanger always start. Hate that. I know whenever i want to use that.

Comment: OK. Now the removed apps improved my battery lifetime, and after that today morning, now i checked what was the most used process. It was google map. Now (i understood your answer), how can i tilt to start this process when i do not want to run it? Why is it turned on? I turned off all synch except google contact.

If i can solve this issue, i will be happy!

Comment: @lolka_bolka Check out greenify on the play store since you are rooted, it may help. It's a great app, it hibernates applications until they are explicitly opened.