# Are wakelocks only when screen is off?

Tags: battery-life, wakelock

If so, can I block all third-party app wakelocks since I want the apps to run only when my screen is *on*?

I understand that this would break some functionality like receiving whatsapp messages when screen is *off*, but I am fine with it.

Answer (score 0):

> Are wakelocks only when screen is off?

**No**

Quoting from Android Developers

- [PowerManager.WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html) defines *wakelock*

> A wake lock is a mechanism to indicate that your application needs to have the device stay on

- [PowerManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html) defines various *types of wakelocks*

> The following wake lock levels are defined, with varying effects on system power. These levels are mutually exclusive - you may only specify one of them.
>
> [image]

- As you can see from the picture *partial wakelocks* will continue to run irrespective of *state of screen*.

> I want the apps to run only when my screen is on?

This should be possible using [automation](/questions/tagged/automation) but I haven't tried. Another alternative is using a task killer like [[root] Servicely](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.franco.servicely&hl=en) to *choose and selectively kill apps when the screen is on*.

**Note:** Task killers are not recommended for reasons mentioned here [Do I really need to install a task manager?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9/131553) and various other answers in [task-management](/questions/tagged/task-management) tag

For further reading: [Wakelocks: Detect No-Sleep Issues in Android* Applications](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/wakelocks-detect-no-sleep-issues-in-android-applications)

Comment: I have used servicely to control wakelocks despite the warning not to use it- the trick is in carefully configuring it once you identify your offending app